# Live CD doesn't boot, drops to BusyBox shell

Tags: 10.10, boot, live-cd

I am a Windows user and I'm keen to shift to Linux, so I made live CD of Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick). **This is my very first time to use Ubuntu**. I put CD in the drive and set the BIOS to boot it, and the Ubuntu CD worked and logo of Ubuntu appears on screen.

But suddenly before the start up screen it shows this:

```
BusyBox v1.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.31 ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

When I type help and press Enter, the list of commands appear like below:

```
alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec export ...
```

This is my first time so i have no idea what to do. I restarted my pc several times but it happens every time. Please help me. What should I do?

Comment: Which version of the live CD did you download?

Comment: It might be that your graphics are unsupported, but I can't be sure without more information. Can you add some info about the system as well? (**That's if, *and only if* burning a fresh CD doesn't work again**). You could also try pressing a key when the keyboard icon comes up within the first few seconds, and then using other options (F6) to see if an option (such as disabling Kernel Mode Setting) works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try burning again. If doesn't work, re-download and burn again. Go for the torrent version, it's fastest and most reliable.