# Installation to external hard drive - not booting

Tags: 12.04, boot, external-hdd

I have the same problem as [Why does my external hard drive not boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165183/why-does-my-external-hard-drive-not-boot)

I tried all suggested solutions on the web even I removed the internal hard drive and I let the installation use all the external hard drive size to install it but it still not able to boot.

laptop: emachine e730* core i3
external hard drive: Apacer 1TB AC233 USB3.0 Portable External

Comment: That might not be easy to solve. It looks like your BIOS does not detect the external drive as a hard disk. If your machine has both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports, try to use the 2.0 port as well, for many mainboards have an additional USB 3.0 chip that might be the cause of your trouble. If this doesn't help, check the BIOS, if there's a setting called something like USB emulation type and set it to HDD.

Comment: Could you please update/edit your question confirming that your external hard drive is in BIOS settings menu and one time boot device list and that BIOS is set appropriately to boot that device first?  Please also add what is happening at boot time i.e. does grub screen load after POST and share the errors if any are given?

Comment: The BIOS detect the external drive and it's set to boot first.

Comment: after installing Ubuntu and start it for the first time it hangs on a pink screen then after restarting it the boot menu appear but then it end with the same error as http://askubuntu.com/questions/165183/why-does-my-external-hard-drive-not-boot

Comment: Errors after choosing the recovery mode:

usb 2-1.2 device descriptor read/64, error -110
new high speed usb devise number 4 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.2 device not accepting address 5, error -110
unable to enumerate USB device on port 2

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu by using the real installer, you just need to install GRUB on the internal drive. If you've used the USB-installer, you need to look in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Not all external HDD can be used to boot operative systems. This is a sad truth I had to uncover with my external 500GB Iomega HDD, that requires a power connection. If your external HDD also requires a separate power connection, then it probably won't work.

Another important thing is the interface it uses to communicate with the machine, it should be USB.

PS: I just saw images of your [HDD](http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/Apacer_1TB_AC233)! online, so unless I got the wrong pictures, I believe it should be able to boot an operative system. Looks like the BIOS theory is better.

Comment: My hdd: http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/Apacer_1TB_AC233
Interface used: USB3.0.
The power is from the USB.